# namespace over a #include header file question

Tags: xcode, namespaces, stdint

I porting code from a windows machine to a Mac.  I am using OS X 10.6 with Xcode 3.2.5

I have a header file called api.h which has the following code:

```
namespace ocip {
    #include "onan/ocip/ocip.h"
}
```

ocip.h includes #include stdint.h
which has the following typedef:

```
 typedef unsigned int         uint32_t;
```

Now back to api.h I have class with following in it:

ocip::uint32_t m_nMode;

The compiler tells me that uint32_t in namespace 'ocip' does not name a type.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but a type of "uint32_t" may already be declared.  There is already a typedef of the same name if you are including "stdint".  This could be causing a problem with redefining it in opic.h.

Comment: I just realized that I left out that key word in my question, ocip.h includes stdint.h, which what I was hoping ocip::uint32_t would be.  Does this mean that if I am including stdint.h that I can't use a namespace around it like I am trying in the question?

Comment: Everything inside stdint is in the std namespace.  Try "ocip::std::uint32_t", but I think you might have to move the #include to outside the namespace declaration (before it), and then do "using namespace std"

Comment: It doesn't seems like uint32_t isn't in the std namespace since std::uint32_t doesn't work with or without ocip:: in front of it or with including using namespace std;  When I look into stdint.h it doesn't have a namespace in it either.  It still seems like ocip::uint32_t should work, but it doesn't

Comment: You're right.  Do you have a slight misspelling?  I understand that sounds stupid, but:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/215315

Comment: This actually might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204118/can-i-include-iostream-header-file-into-custom-namespace

Comment: @MichaelWildermuth let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1813/discussion-between-chris-and-michael-wildermuth)